# Can't install @uirouter/angularjs via npm

Tags: angularjs, npm, angular-ui-router, npm-install

Trying to install [@uirouter/angularjs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) via npm, but getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @uirouter/angularjs@1.0.12
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/anatolyt/.npm/_logs/2018-01-10T14_14_22_375Z-debug.log
```

I'm using **node** v8.9.1 and **npm** 5.6.0, I'm using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) too. Using OSX High Sierra - latest.

My package.json file is as following:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@uirouter/angularjs":"1.0.12"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: What command you used?

Comment: I'm using `npm install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected it was related to our private npm repository - [sinopia](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia), it was unable to resolve name which begins from **@**, `@uirouter/angularjs`, `@angular/core`, etc...

Thanks for our IT guy, he found a solution in this thread: [Unable to resolve dependencies like "@angular/common"](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia/issues/399), you need to issue locally:

- `npm config set "@angular:registry" http://registry.npmjs.org/`

it will cause **npm** to bypass **sinopia** and go straight to the npmjs repository for all packages within `@angular` scope. You have to perform same for every scope.

Another permanent solution (untested yet) is to modify sinopia's code:
in `sinopia/lib/up-storage.js`
change code on line number 10

```
var encode  = function(thing) {
  return encodeURIComponent(thing).replace(/^%40/, '@');
};
```